# WinRT 8.1 WebView Content Type

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm trying to load a webview using HttpRequestMessage in Windows Phone 8.1. The problem is that the Content-Type header is missing in the content headers when checked in Fiddler.

```
            byte[] postData = GetWebviewPostDataBytes();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, prepareUri(url));
            var httpContent = new HttpBufferContent(postData.AsBuffer());
            httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", GetContentType());
            request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", GetUserAgent());
            request.Content = httpContent;
            webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request);
```

I found some links where this is posed as an internal bug. Can someone tell me a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found for this is to use a form to load your page.

I'm loading a local HTML page which I'm generating with my POST parameters. This page contains an hidden HTML form which I will submit once the page will be loaded.

The web page loading is then:

1. generate a local HTML page with a form and your parameters in hidden input fields
2. load this page in your webview
3. once the page is loaded, request a submit of the form using the webpage postContent() function
4. the webview will then navigate to the expected webpage with the content-type header set

This sample code is in WinJS but it can easily be transposed in C# since it is the same webview component.

```
var htmlContent     = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>function postContent(){document.getElementById('postForm').submit();}</script></head><body><form id='postForm' action='{targetUrl}' method='post'>{inputFields}</form></body></html>";
var inputFields     = "";
var iterator        = payloadContent.first();
while(iterator.hasCurrent)
{
    inputFields     += "<input hidden='on' name='{n}' value='{v}'/>".replace("{n}", iterator.current.key).replace("{v}", iterator.current.value);
    iterator.moveNext();
}
var htmlContent     = htmlContent.replace("{targetUrl}", "YOUR URL HERE").replace("{inputFields}", inputFields);
this._webviewElement.navigateToString(htmlContent);
```

In the page loaded event you will then have to request the webview to execute the 'postContent()' javascript function to submit the form.

```
this._webviewElement.invokeScriptAsync("postContent");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Used similar approach for my solution.